# Practices for Logging in a desktop application

Tags: logging

We are developing a desktop application(visual basic 6.0).We have our own logging framework. What are good practices? When we have a web application, then we can control the level of logging. How to go about in a desktop app?

Answer (score 8):

Any answer needs to be considered based on your environment:

- Do your business rules (or laws) *require* certain activities to be logged?
- Is security an issue?
- Do actions need to be traceable?
- Is the size of the log file (or the amount of disk space) an issue?
- Is your motivation to record activity, to debug, or both?

With those in mind:

- Consider allowing the user to select the verbosity, or "logging level."
- Log all program errors and significant user errors.
- Log any activities that affect system configuration or operation.
- Log the start and end of user sessions.
- Log the start and end of the application.
- Consider logging the first time a significant activity occurs.

Other suggestions:

- Include timestamps, either in each log or at the beginning of a "group" of logs, as best appropriate for your application.
- If you're logging to a file, consider rotating the log (*i.e.* closing one file and opening a new one) when it reaches a certain size or age.
- If the application contains several modules, include the name of the module in each log.
- If more than one person uses the application (shared computer?), log the user ID at the beginning of each session.
- Assign log "levels" based on the severity (Error, Warning, Info, Debug).  The `syslog` specification defines 7 "standard" levels that serve as a good reference.
- Ask your customer what they expect to see in the log.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Messing around with a Swing desktop application, and I realized today I needed to do SOME kind of logging so they would have something to hand me if the program misbehaves or breaks (and it will).

Comment: +1 for recognizing this before it happens!  If you're using logs to debug, it helps to be able to predict the future.  Imagine yourself six months from now, reading the logs to find out what happened.  What information will you wish you had?  Now's your chance to give yourself that data.  You may also want to make it as easy as possible for the client to send the logs to you.  Can you make it a one-click process?  Automate it completely?  The easier it is, the more likely you'll receive the logs when you need them.  Good luck!

Comment: Great answer. I will add to it: consider adding a short unique id (i.e. e-vushcue, e-v93dc3i, e-3vjw9c3...) to each error message, then you can very quickly reference it if it occurs in production (where in some cases having to pinpoint where it happened exactly could be very hard).

Answer (score 0):

An important feature to consider is to allow for adjustment of the log level dynamically at run time without requiring stopping and restarting the application (I've implemented this on *nix with a custom signal handler). This is a great help when debugging in the field.

Many times, a misbehaving application will behave fine when restarted. Dynamically tweakable log levels let you see whats going on before you release all your resources back to the OS.